The “View all” community buttons in the Community user's site profiles link to a server error page
When I click the “View all” community button on the Community bot profile page, it links to the page  as shown below:



It shows that “Oops! Something Bad Happened!”. Is there any reason for this error? I just found that this issue only happened in the “Community Bot”, not on other users.

Well it does have network profile, but without accounts, hence it errors out when you try to access them.  The bug is actually that there is a link to it, it should not show in the Community profile page.

As one with over 100 suggested edits, I find it very odd that you approved a random trolling suggestion, care to explain? I mean, you know how it works. You know you can, and should, reject bad edits. Not "improve" them.

status-completed

I don’t know when did this change. But it works for me now.

See the Community Bot profile.
Click the “View All” button which is on the profile page.
It links  to the Community Bot network profile page.

Here is a screenshot for it:

Thanks, unknown developer.
